Is it possible to have a planet that's gaslike in some areas and rocky in others?
Specifically if a planet is an oblate spheroid with a large enough bulge at the equator, could the higher gravity areas hold onto hydrogen and helium, resulting in there not really being a "surface", whereas the lower gravity areas would remain rocky?

Well, perhaps if you'd added the [science-fantasy] tag...... (Somewhat too late not for the already-given answers.)

Anything is possible with magic or alternate physics. If you mean is it realistic; than the answer is no.

The highest mountain on Venus is 10km, but if you put the 20km Olympus Mons on it, I think the temperature and pressure would be just below the critical point, so the atmosphere would be definitively a gas and not a supercritical fluid. Still like 20x denser and higher pressure than earth, but like... maybe it's something? If you cool down a Venus, I'm not sure what the math says would happen, but maybe it's an angle.

If you put Olympus Mons on Venus, Olympus Mons will collapse.  It might last long enough for humans to visit, but I wouldn't count on it.

Such planets exist; the arrangement of solid and gaseous matter is usually in shells ;-).

One might say we are already living on/in such a planet, if the gas and rock are regarded as layers with differing distance from the center. Thus Earth may be regarded as having a thin gaseous layer, its atmosphere, around the rocky matter (and iron-based metal further in). Giant planets such as Jupiter are believed to have rocky cores, even more massive than Earth, deep within their huge gaseous/supercritical fluid layers. In between is Venus. Like Earth, this planet is primarily its rocky/iron components. But as with Jupiter, its rock cannot be seen from space and its gaseous layer (atmosphe

"Specifically if a planet is an oblate spheroid with a large enough bulge at the equator" a big enough bulge in a large enough body to be called a planet for what you want probably isn't possible, it's own gravity will force it into a more ordinary sphere.

The layers aren't regarded as that, though; the OP's very clear that they want to know if it would be possible for a planet to have some regions where the planet could hold onto enough atmosphere to be gas giant-like all the way from top to bottom and some regions where it's terrestrial all the way from top to bottom. They aren't asking about actual planetary composition, but the realism of the worldbuilding they want to do for the story they're working on.

No, not really. Gravity gradient makes so that matters is arranged according to density, forcing the densest material to sink below the less dense.
Therefore having hydrogen below rock would not be possible in the long term.

Why does oil under the rock works all the time?

@alamar it doesn't. oil forms underground and tries to migrate ot the surface, only in completely watertight rock does it get trapped.

Further, the oil isn't "under" the rock, it's inside the rock, in the pores of the rock's structure.  Same with water and natural gas (or volcanic gases).

No
The primary issue is that the planetoid is an entity which surface is shaped according to its own gravity, and a planet is more so, thus you can't really get "more gravity at the equator" to capture hydrogen. The capabiliy of a planet to capture hydrogen is determined against its entirety, not a region, because the atmosphere is not static, it has all kinds of winds inside, and winds are created when there is a pressure gradient. Here on Earth a pressure gradient of mere 20 mmHg (600 Pa? lazy) causes fourth grade storms, and here you ask for at atmospheric gradient of a thousand TIMES NORMAL PRESSURE. This is impossible in nature. Thus it's either the planet does capture hydrogen, which means the amount of hydrogen in the planet's gravity well increases over time, or it does not.

Larry Niven's Known Space setting has two planets with something like what you're after.
One is called Plateau or Mount Lookitthat; it's a Venus-like atmosphere with a single flat-topped mountain sticking up roundly 40 miles (64 km) from the average surface.  The main atmosphere is too dense to breathe and full of toxic gasses, but at the top of the Mountain it's much like Earth's.  See A Gift from Earth for more.
The other is Jinx.  Jinx is egg-shaped, having formed in an orbit close to a huge gas giant (brown dwarf?) and has a "fossil tidal bulge" but in geologically recent time, its orbit has migrated away from the primary.  Being tide locked, it now has two ends of bare rock sticking up out of the atmosphere, but the atmospheric depth a the tidal equator is such that breathing it is like breathing regular air five hundred meters down in Earth's oceans; the only things that survive there are pre-human creatures bred for food by the race that commanded the galaxy a billion years ago.  I don't recall any stories actually set on Jinx, but natives of the high gravity super-moon are featured in several tales.

Note that both of these situations are unstable, possibly too unstable to actually exist.

@Mark Both are temporary on a geological timeframe -- but (at least as of the early 1970s when Gift was published) there was reason to believe an Earthlike planet could, over a period of a few million years at least, support a 40 mile tall mountain.  Jinx keeping the egg shape with the ends sticking up out of the atmosphere is a lot less likely, especially with a surface gravity of ~3 G; rock is fluid on a planetary scale -- but it made a good story basis and allowed suspension of disbelief.

Hmm, how oblate is this spheroid?
If you, somehow, spin the earth 17 times as fast as it is now, so a day only lasts 84 minutes, you would feel a net 0 g at the equator (Whee!), while still feeling 1 g at the polls.
Since Jupiter's surface gravity is only 2.528 g you just have to mass up the earth until it's 2.528 g at the polls and spin it until it's 1g (2.528-1.528=1) at the equator.
Gravity comes from mass. Spin is just rotation causing centripetal force. These two things are why the earth is a oblate spheroid (squished ball) right now. You don't need a solid rocky body for this to happen. Earth isn't a solid rocky body anyway. It's mostly gooey inside.
If you want to say this can't happen you need a better argument than rocks falling down. Oblate spheroid is the stable shape. For both the 'rocky' Earth and the gassy Jupiter. When a rock falls, it falls into this shape.

on such a planet won't the rocks sink until gravity is roughly the same everywhere. rock is not that strong.

I don't think this would achieve what the OP wants: the atmosphere overall would be thicker at the poles and thinner at the equator, yeah, but the absolutely massive wind currents that this kind of pressure gradient would produce would mean that any hydrogen or helium that started to build up at the poles would be more than able to get further south and eventually outgas. The overall composition of the atmosphere would still be generally the same everywhere on the planet.

@Idran I don't think pressure gradients produce wind. For example, the ocean has massive pressure gradients. Yet what produces ocean currents is uneven heating. You can't use a pressure gradient to get energy. You need a source of energy for that.

Oh, good point; I was thinking of fronts on Earth, but that's more due to the thermal difference than the pressure difference. Still, though, I can't imagine the weather patterns on a world like this as being calm in general (Coriolis would play a much bigger role, for one), so I think the atmospheric composition would still generally be equalized and you'd still have that equatorial outgassing effect for any captured hydrogen and helium?

@Idran there you have a point. Hydrogen and helium would head “uphill” (to the equator) in the presence of heavier gases. Meaning they would out gas against 1g.

I think it's possible if you consider a double planet system in very close proximity. Think Earth+moon, but both very similar size and both very very close (one or two diameters top). They would then have tidelocked orbits and any atmosphere or sea would accumulate around the point of closest proximity, leaving the opposite side bare. If the planets are close enough and the atmosphere dense enough, an animal could possibly fly from one planet to the other. Gravity would also be weaker at the closest point than on the opposite side.
Such a system was described in Rocheworld by Robert Forward in 1984. The guy was a physicist but I don't know how realistic that is.

Better reexamine your physics.  In Rocheworld it was made clear that the ocean on Eau filled the Roche lobe -- and yes, it climbed well up into the "neck" between the two bodies (even slopped over a bit at times) during "high tide" (when the star was aligned with the twin planets, depending on orbital position and distance), but not at the expense of the opposite pole; the ocean was deeper there, too, but there was no neutral point to slop into.
